# How to launch the Desktop

Tags: c#, desktop

I have a button which currently runs explorer:-

```
private void _mJobsExplorer(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

            Process.Start(@"C:\");
}
```

I need to be able to launch the Desktop instead.  Launching explorer that points to Desktop is not enough.

I have created a Desktop.scf, that launches the Desktop, but I don't know how to launch this within c# either.

I would prefer to launch Desktop straight from the code instead of calling a program that launches Desktop.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is "launch the desktop"? Do you actually mean "show the desktop"?

Comment: Surely you can get the desktop path with `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` and use `Process.Start` to open that folder? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean, like... minimize all windows so you can see the desktop? If so, that'd probably be a clearer way to phrase this.

Comment: Yes I want to minimise all windows to get to the desktop, like when you press show desktop on the taskbar.

Comment: A search on `show desktop programmatically c#` leads to [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2004/02/24/programmatically-showing-the-desktop-toggledesktop/)

Comment: This worked for me with a slight tweak of removing the references to Class. Shell32.Shell objShel = new Shell32.Shell();

            // Show the desktop
            ((Shell32.IShellDispatch4)objShel).ToggleDesktop();

Comment: Do you really need to put this in your app? Just use `Windows+D` keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The app hides the taskbar and Window+D does not work, hence the need to show the Desktop via a button.

Comment: Are you just wanting the app to run as the only thing visible on the machine, in other words, in kiosk mode?